# How To get access to edit UILabel by using a class function inside the viewController

Tags: swift, uicontrol

ViewController has a textField called userInput which allow user to add a value, so i want to change the label name when user press the button of calculate. I used a class to modify label name, when calling viewController label from inside the class xcode shows "viewController does not have a member name userAnswer" But my code does have a label called userAnswer.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var userInput: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var userTo: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var userValue: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
        var textboxValue = userValue.text.toInt()

        if textboxValue != nil {

            if selection1 == 0 {

                let milimeter = Milimeter()
                milimeter.toCnverter(textboxValue!, item: selection2)
                userAnswer.text = " "

            } else if selection1 == 1 {

            } else if selection1 == 2 {

            } else if selection1 == 3 {

            } else if selection1 == 4 {

            }


        } else {

            userAnswer.text = "Please enter a Value"
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet var userAnswer: UILabel!

    let length1 = ["Milimeter","Centimeter","Inch","Meter","Kilometer"]
    let length2 = ["Milimeter","Centimeter","Inch","Meter","Kilometer"]
    var selection1 = 0
    var selection2 = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        userInput.delegate = self
        userInput.dataSource = self

        userTo.delegate = self
        userTo.dataSource = self
    }

    class Milimeter {

        func toCnverter(value: Int, item: Int) {

            switch item {

            case 0:
                userAnswer.text = " " // i can't access , shows error
            case 1:
                println("Inch")

            case 2:
                println("Kilometer")

            default:
                println(" ")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten to connect the `UILabel` from the `UIStoryboard`, with the `UILabel` in your code. To be 100% sure, delete the variable from your code and reconnect the outlet from the `UIStoryboard` to your code.

**Edit after seeing the whole code:**

Your `class` Millimeter does not know of your `UILabel` since it is not an attribute of it, but an attribute of the `UIViewController`.

My recommendation: `func toConverter` should return what it converts. That makes it also testable -> `func toConverter(value: Int, item: Int) -> String`

Your `if-statement` would look like this:

```
if selection1 == 0 {
  let milimeter = Milimeter() 
  userAnswer.text = milimeter.toCnverter(textboxValue!, item: selection2)
}
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3) is some more information on `Access Control` in swift

Comment: i did connected, i can make changes but not within the Millimeter class :) ( i  posted the code )

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an `IBOutlet` of the label in your .h file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *userAnswer;
```

Try accessing it by `self.userAnswer`

Comment: The question is about Swift, which does not have .h files.

Comment: The code is shared after I answered the question :).